# SVN how to automatically commit into multiple branches?

Tags: svn

I have like 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 branches and i want every commit that goesw into 1.0 to go automatically to 1.1 and 1.2 and every commit to 1.1 to go automatically get committed to 1.2

is it possible to make all this in a single transaction and automatically? can someone tell me how please? (can it be with example please?)

Comment: Your SVN branches aren't supposed to be complete copies of the trunk.  Your branches should only contain the modules that have changed.  If you want a version 1.1 and a version 1.2, you would use tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. You can make it atomic if you checkout the whole repository (or at least the branches folder). It won't be automatic though. You will have to apply the changes your self to the other branches. The different branches presumably have different code (you said they were version branches), so applying the same fix to different branches may require different edits. You can't (in general), always avoid human intervention.

I would challenge the idea of making everything look like 1 transaction. That will adversely impact the quality of your history. It will look like you made independant changed in many places. If you make the merging to other branches a separate transaction then the history will better reflect what you actually did (making one change and back porting it). Is there a reason you need to edit all branches in 1 Transaction?

Comment: In this case you cannot stress that "this is not a good idea" part strong enough.

Comment: I wanted that if there is a conflict in an automatic merge into 1.1 from 1.0 for example to notify the user and tell him you cannot commit your changes you must first resolve the conflicts with 1.1 before you commit and then only if user commits with some keyword like "I resolved conflicts with 1.1" to let him commit his changes to 1.0

Comment: You can do that check with a post commit hook. An alternative approach might be to use a continuous integration server like Team City, or to hire testers.